# MS Access front end TransferText readonly error

Tags: ms-access

I am maintaining an application which uses an access mdb file as a front end to SQL Server, using odbc linked tables.

I would like to make the mdb file readonly (otherwise the file just grows and grows as users use it, and some occasional odd locking errors not relating to data but to the access application).

Since all the data is in sql, the application should work just fine even if I make the mdb file readonly, and in fact it does work for the most part, except...

Part of the application uses DoCmd.TransferText to import various text files into various tables. if the mdb file is readonly I get  runtime error 3051 error "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ... it is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data".

I can't see any reason for this error, since I am not writing any data to the mdb file itself. (and I also noticed in the 'External Data' ribbon all the 'import' buttons are greyed out).

any suggestions?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Since all the data is in sql, the application should work just fine even if I make the mdb file readonly

Not necessarily. You are using the .mdb file as an application so it may well need to update local temporary tables or other objects in the .mdb file.

Furthermore, if you are using an .mdb front end then each user ***must*** be given their own local copy of that file, so file bloat is essentially a non-issue and you can just let the users have write access to the local file.

Comment: a: we have tested the application as readonly and so far the only issue we encountered was the error on DoCmd.TransferText (although it's possible that DoCmd.TransferText internally uses temporary tables).

Comment: b: why does 'each user MUST be given their own local copy', why is that a MUST?

Comment: @mendel it is a must because a front-end access database is meant to be accessible to a single user at a time. Whether you want it or not the front-end may need to update its internal objects based on factors outside of your control (temporary tables for some functions for instance). Sharing the front-end accross a network will decrease performance as code and forms etc have to be read accross the network instead of the local disc AND you are likely to encounter strange errors, bugs and crashes over time. It's just not good practice with Access front-ends. Only share the data, not the UI.

Comment: @RenaudBompuis thanks, I understand the benefits, I was only questioning the **must**, in a small deployment a shared front end is simpler and works well enough. I have a deployed application where the front end is marked read only and used by 15-20 users with rare problems, certainly not enough to make individual front ends a **must**.